# Test exec that requires interactive input in Golang

Tags: shell, go, exec, fzf

Am trying to use [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) in a Go code. I referred to the example given [here](https://junegunn.kr/2016/02/using-fzf-in-your-program) by the author. When I tried to write a test for the function its getting stuck as `fzf` requires interactive input.

Code:

```
func withFilter(command string, input func(in io.WriteCloser)) []string {
    shell := os.Getenv("SHELL")
    if len(shell) == 0 {
        shell = "sh"
    }
    cmd := exec.Command(shell, "-c", command)
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    in, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
    go func() {
        input(in)
        in.Close()
    }()
    result, _ := cmd.Output()
    return strings.Split(string(result), "\n")
}

func filter() []string {
    filtered := withFilter("fzf -m", func(in io.WriteCloser) {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Fprintln(in, i)
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    })

    return filtered
}
```

Test:

```
func TestFilter(t *testing.T) {
    assert.Equal(t, []string{"1", "2", "3"}, filter())
}
```

I tried debugging and noticed that it gets stuck at `cmd.Output()`. By digging a bit deeper it looks like the command is waiting indefinitely for input, however am not sure how to provide it programatically. I tried writing `\n` to `os.Stdin` but it didn't work.

Anyone pointers or explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of go: Its `io.Reader`/`io.Writer` interfaces.

You have to provide from where your `withFilter` (and by extension `filter`) method should read. So, `in` has to be provided it.

```
// example

func readFrom(reader io.Reader) {
    r := bufio.NewScanner(reader)

    for r.Scan() {
        fmt.Println("got", r.Text())
    }

    fmt.Println("Done.")
}

func main() {
    const input = "Now is the winter of our discontent,\nMade glorious summer by this sun of York.\n"

    readFrom(strings.NewReader(input))

    // okay, with stdin
    readFrom(os.Stdin)

}
```

As you can see, the first `readFrom` is fully testable, you just change the `input` variable to whatever you want to test. The second `readFrom` will only return when the `stdin` is closed.

The solution is *not* to write to `os.Stdin`. Consider `os.Stdin` an implementation detail in your OS—not something you have to include in your testing.

https://play.golang.org/p/D2wzHYrV2TM *(os.Stdin is closed in the playground)*

Comment: I couldn't relate how `in` could be provided to the `filter/withFilter` function